# total values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

i have this data in MongoDB:

```
   {
    _id: ObjectId("6022e4e634c94918cc1c4b1e"),
    fiscal_year: 2020,
    donor_expend: ["-327.00"],
    donors: ["00012"],
    crs: "74020",
    operating_unit: "BWA",
    name: "Environment Policies for Sustainable Development",
    donor_countries: ["UNDP"],
    focus_area: ["19", "2"],
    donor_budget: ["0.00"],
    expenditure: "-327.00",
    donor_types: ["NON_GOVERNMENT"],
    core: true,
    budget: "0.00",
    id: "00059811",
    region: "RBA",
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6022e4e634c94918cc1c4b1f"),
    fiscal_year: 2020,
    donor_expend: ["9017.00"],
    donors: ["11248"],
    crs: "73010",
    operating_unit: "BRA",
    name:
      "BRA/08/023 - Biodiversity Conservation and Promotion of Social and Environmental Development",
    donor_countries: ["BRA"],
    focus_area: ["1", "19"],
    donor_budget: ["162669.00"],
    expenditure: "9017.00",
    donor_types: ["PROG CTY"],
    core: false,
    budget: "162669.00",
    id: "00051435",
    region: "RBLAC",
  }
```

each id represents a project for an operating_unit
i need to get the total number of projects for each operating_unit as well as the sum of budgets and the sum of expenditures
i'm new to MongoDB and here is what i tried so far:

```
db.project.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$operating_unit",
    total: { $sum: 1 },
    budget: { $sum: "$budget" },
    expenditure: { $sum: "$expenditure" },
  },
});
```

it doesn't give me the sum of the budgets or the expenditure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing budget and expenditure as string, it should rather be as decimal.

But for now, there is the query:

```
db.project.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$operating_unit",
    total: { $sum: 1 },
    budget: { $sum: { $toDecimal: "$budget" } },
    expenditure: { $sum: { $toDecimal: "$expenditure" } },
  },
});
```

and once you are have used correct data types, then you can use:

```
db.project.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$operating_unit",
    total: { $sum: 1 },
    budget: { $sum: "$budget" },
    expenditure: { $sum: "$expenditure" },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Yahya it works, you're a life saver